# Division by zero laravel

Tags: laravel, zero, divide-by-zero

I have a percentage calculation, but if no data is available, I get the following error message:

```
Division by zero
```

calculation

```
$ratio = ($postup*100)/($postup + $postdown);
```

Comment: Just do a check on `$postup + $postdown` expression before dividing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devision by zero is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).

If both `$postup` and `$postdown` are `null` (not set) you will get a division by zero i.e. `null + null == 0`.

Furthermore the same problem will occur if `$postup * -1 == $postdown`.

Since a division by zero is undefined you will need to add a fallback for this.

What this fallback would be is application specific but would look something like

```
$ratio = null;

if($postup + $postdown == 0) {
    $ratio = xxx;
} else {
    $ratio = ($postup*100)/($postup + $postdown);
}
```

Please also be aware that `$postup * 100` will be equal to `0` if `$postup == null`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this, like the following to get rid of the error:

```
$ratio = 0;
$dividedBy = $postup + $postdown;

if($dividedBy != 0) {
    $ratio = ($postup * 100) / $dividedBy;
    echo $ratio;
} else {
    echo "Can not divide by zero!!";
}
```